# Escaping @ sign in a link in Razor

Tags: c#, razor

I have a link with an @ sign inside my razor view.

like so: example.com/@problem

I tryed the following:

- Escaping @ using @@
- Putting my string in myString block
- Verbatim string
- Encoding @ as &#64 and %40
- Putting my string in Html.Raw(myString)

and various combinations of the above. But i keep getting the following Parser error:

Parserfehlermeldung: "problem" is not valid at the start of a code block.  Only identifiers, keywords, comments, "(" and "{" are valid.
I checked various other answers but nothing worked for me.

Comment: The secound point in my List i meant to put myString in < t e x t > tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this works fine for me `@Html.Raw("example.com.@tt")` and so does this `@Html.Raw("<text>example.com.@tt</text>")`

Comment: it worked, maybe i was mixing to much stuff alrdeady :P